# When i add ios platform using IONIC 4 or greater this type of error show again and again

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, cocoapods

Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" for ios
"framework" tag with type "podspec" is deprecated and will be removed. Please use the "podspec" tag.
Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

Usage:

```
$ pod COMMAND

  CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
```

Commands:

```
+ cache        Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
+ env          Display pod environment
+ init         Generate a Podfile for the current directory
+ install      Install project dependencies according to versions from a
               Podfile.lock
+ ipc          Inter-process communication
+ lib          Develop pods
+ list         List pods
+ outdated     Show outdated project dependencies
+ repo         Manage spec-repositories
+ setup        Setup the CocoaPods environment
+ spec         Manage pod specs
+ update       Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock
```

Options:

```
--allow-root   Allows CocoaPods to run as root
--silent       Show nothing
--version      Show the version of the tool
--verbose      Show more debugging information
--no-ansi      Show output without ANSI codes
--help         Show help banner of specified command
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:102:in `ensure_not_root_or_allowed!'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/administrator/Desktop/blank/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:136:25)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:668:12)
```

pod: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

Usage:

```
$ pod COMMAND

  CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
```

Commands:

```
+ cache        Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
+ env          Display pod environment
+ init         Generate a Podfile for the current directory
+ install      Install project dependencies according to versions from a
               Podfile.lock
+ ipc          Inter-process communication
+ lib          Develop pods
+ list         List pods
+ outdated     Show outdated project dependencies
+ repo         Manage spec-repositories
+ setup        Setup the CocoaPods environment
+ spec         Manage pod specs
+ update       Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock
```

Options:

```
--allow-root   Allows CocoaPods to run as root
--silent       Show nothing
--version      Show the version of the tool
--verbose      Show more debugging information
--no-ansi      Show output without ANSI codes
--help         Show help banner of specified command
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:102:in `ensure_not_root_or_allowed!'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova platform add ios exited with exit code 1.
    
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
    information.
```

Comment: and what happens when you don't run it as root?

Comment: when i add ios platform this type error show   Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)